# Mocking and stubbing in testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I've recently learned how to stub in rspec and found that some benefits of it are we can decouple the code (eg. controller and model), more efficient test execution (eg. stubbing database call).

However I figured that if we stub, the code can be tightly tied to a particular implementation which therefore sacrifice the way we refactor the code later.

Example:

UsersController

```
# /app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    User.create(name: params[:name])
  end
end
```

Controller spec

```
# /spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it 'saves new user' do
      expect(User).to receive(:create)
      post :create, :name => "abc"
    end
  end
end
```

By doing that didn't I just limit the implementation to only using `User.create`? So later if I change the code my test will fail even though the purpose of both code is the same which is to save the new user to database

```
# /app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new
    @user.name = params[:name]
    @user.save!
  end
end
```

Whereas if I test the controller without stubbing, I can create a real record and later check against the record in the database. As long as the controller is able to save the user Like so

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it 'saves new user' do
      post :create, :name => "abc"
      user = User.first
      expect(user.name).to eql("abc")
    end
  end
end
```

Really sorry if the codes don't look right or have errors, I didn't check the code but you get my point.

So my question is, can we mock/stub without having to be tied to a particular implementation? If so, would you please throw me an example in rspec

Answer (score 1):

You should use mocking and stubbing to simulate services *external* to the code, which it uses, but you are not interested in them running in your test.

For example, say your code is using the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter):

```
status = client.status(my_client)
```

In your test, you don't *really* want your code to go to twitter API and get your bogus client's status! Instead you stub that method:

```
expect(client).to receive(:status).with(my_client).and_return("this is my status!")
```

Now you can safely check your code, with deterministic, short running results!

This is one use case where stubs and mocks are useful, there are more. Of course, like any other tool, they may be abused, and cause pain later on.

Comment: so are you saying that in my example, better not to mock the code?

Comment: @verdy yes, mocking is not suitable for your case. There are gems and methodologies for testing these kinds of things

Answer (score 0):

Internally create calls save and new

```
def create(attributes = nil, options = {}, &block)
  if attributes.is_a?(Array)
    attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, options, &block) }
  else
    object = new(attributes, options, &block)
    object.save
    object
  end
end
```

So possibly your second test would cover both cases.

It is not straight forward to write tests which are implementation independent. That's why integration tests have a lot of value and are better suited than unit tests for testing the behavior of the application.

Comment: but again later in integration test, if I mock some code, wouldn't it be implementation dependent? so it would depend again entirely on the method being mocked?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you're presented, you're not exactly mocking or stubbing. Let's take a look at the first spec:

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it 'saves new user' do
      expect(User).to receive(:create)
      post :create, :name => "abc"
    end
  end
end
```

Here, you're testing that User received the 'create' message. You're right that there's something wrong with this test because it's going to break if you change the implementation of the controllers 'create' action, which defeats the purpose of testing. Tests should be flexible to change and not a hinderance.

What you want to do is not test implementation, but side effects. What is the controller 'create' action supposed to do? It's supposed to create a user. Here's how I would test it

```
# /spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it 'saves new user' do
      expect { post :create, name: 'abc' }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

As for mocking and stubbing, I try to stay away from too much stubbing. I think it's super useful when you're trying to test conditionals. Here's an example:

```
# /app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)

    if user.save
      flash[:success] = 'User created'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Something went wrong'
      render 'new'
  end
end

# /spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it "renders new if didn't save" do
      User.any_instance.stub(:save).and_return(false)
      post :create, name: 'abc'
      expect(response).to render_template('new')
    end
  end
end
```

Here I'm stubbing out 'save' and returning 'false' so I can test what's supposed to happen if the user fails to save.

Also, the other answers were correct in saying that you want to stub out external services so you don't call on their API every time you're running your test suite.

Comment: In your "it saves new user" example, does that mean I still have to make a call to database? In other word we can't completely eliminate the need of calling external service in a test?

Comment: In this example it would still hit the database, which would make test a little slower I think. You could stub out the call to the database. But I find that controller tests shouldn't really be unit tests. They should be functional tests. So you want to hit the database from the controller to make sure it's actually saving the record here. But if you are calling an external service to save the record, I would stub out that external service.